# Android app crash on android < 5.0 (on 4.x)

Tags: java, android, facebook-android-sdk, google-signin

Aplication crash on android 5.0 <, but on android => 5.0 it works.
I test this app on my asus zenfone 5 (Android 5.0) and it works, but i test it on smasung galaxy S III (Android 4.3 and Android 4.1) app crash.

Here is my JAVA CODE:

```
package cz.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 007;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    public String Email;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Google+
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        //Facebook
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.facebook_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");

            loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    // Facebook Email address
                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(
                                        JSONObject object,
                                        GraphResponse response) {

                                    try {
                                        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.log_tag), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

                                        Email = object.getString("email");
                                        editor.putString("email", Email);
                                        editor.commit();
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class));
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "id,email");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException e) {

                }
            });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    public void Facebook(View v) {
        loginButton.performClick();
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.log_tag), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("first", "true");
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void google(View v) {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.log_tag), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("first", "true");
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void preskoc(View v) {
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.log_tag), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("first", "true");
        editor.commit();
        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            Email = acct.getEmail();

            sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.log_tag), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("email", Email);
            editor.commit();
            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

ADB LOGCAT:

```
INFO|11-29 12:47:09.860|769|769||dalvikvm|  at cz.www3.tech_apps.cinetube.cinetube.Login.onCreate(Login.java:58)
ERROR|11-29 12:47:09.865|769|769||AndroidRuntime|   at cz.www3.tech_apps.cinetube.cinetube.Login.onCreate(Login.java:58)
INFO|11-29 12:47:10.175|2358|11814||WindowManager|Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{427b8988 ActivityRecord{43fbb600 u0 cz.www3.tech_apps.cinetube.cinetube/.Login}} appWin=Window{44605dd0 u0 Starting cz.www3.tech_apps.cinetube.cinetube} drawState=4
DEBUG|11-29 12:47:18.330|2358|2483||CrashAnrDetector|processName: cz.www3.tech_apps.cinetube.cinetube
DEBUG|11-29 12:47:18.330|2358|2483||CrashAnrDetector|broadcastEvent : cz.www3.tech_apps.cinetube.cinetube data_app_crash
```

FULL ADB LOG:

```
    DEBUG|11-29 13:28:49.085|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime|Shutting down VM
|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime|  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.0ERROR95|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime|FATAL EXCEPTION: main
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime|java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1076)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1017)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:60)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:131)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:56)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
ERROR|11-29 13:28:49.095|3269|3269||AndroidRuntime| at cz.www3.tech_apps.cinetube.cinetube.Login.onCreate(Login.java:58)
INFO|11-29 13:28:49.100|2358|5054||ActivityManager|Notify an ApplicationCrash
WARNING|11-29 13:28:49.400|2358|5054||WindowManager|Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (720x1280) to layer 21020
INFO|11-29 13:28:49.400|2358|5054||WindowManager|Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{42cfe360 ActivityRecord{44020028 u0 cz.www3.tech_apps.cinetube.cinetube/.Login}} appWin=Window{428a6070 u0 Starting cz.www3.tech_apps.cinetube.cinetube} drawState=4
INFO|11-29 13:28:49.405|2358|2483||power|*** release_dvfs_lock : lockType : 1
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/facebook_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:id="@+id/loginobrazek"
            android:src="@drawable/login" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_cinetube"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="Přihlašte se přes"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tvText"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvText"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="210dp">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fb"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:background="#416BC1"
                    android:onClick="Facebook"
                    android:text="FaceBook"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/gp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:onClick="google"
                    android:text="GOOGLE +"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/preskoc"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
                    android:onClick="preskoc"
                    android:text="nebo přeskočit"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is at `Login.java:58`? And what is the full exception cause in the logcat ?

Comment: On line 58 is `setContentView(R.layout.login);`

Comment: Please show that layout. Your device is apparently running out of memory by loading that xml

Comment: I add layout code to my question

Comment: If you remove the drawables on the Imageviews, will it run on that device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older androids sucks at handling big bitmaps - you'r device is running of ouf memory, and bitmaps are expensive on a heap.

You can try using lower-resolution image for older devices, making ImageView smaller, or use 3rd party library specialized in loading bitmaps:

- Picasso http://square.github.io/picasso/

or

- Glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide